# Database connections still in use after query on sqlx in a golang project

Tags: go, sqlx

I'm working in a golang project using sqlx and postgres. When the application starts I open a connection with the database and use it like this:

```
var connRO *sqlx.DB
var connRW *sqlx.DB
...

/ GetInstance - will return the connection opened to the database
func GetInstance(readonly bool) *sqlx.DB {

    if readonly {
        return connRO
    }

    return connRW
}
```

The problem is that in some blocks of code the connection still in use, here one example:

```
instanceRW := database.GetInstance(false)
instanceRO := database.GetInstance(true)
...

err := instanceRO.Get(&idFuncionario, `
            SELECT id 
            FROM t_funcionario 
            WHERE codigo_externo = $1 `,
            i.FuncionarioID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return errors.New("Erro ao identificar funcionário.")
        }

        // Verifica se o item é granel
        // Caso não seja
        if *i.ItemGranelID == 0 {
            // Verifica se o item está disponível
            err = instanceRO.Get(&localidade_id, `
                SELECT COALESCE(localidade_id, 0) 
                FROM t_item 
                WHERE id = $1
            `, i.ItemID)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return errors.New("Não foi possível identificar tipo do item.")
...
            }
```

When I try test it doing something like it, the test don't open many connections. Here some test code:

```
i := 600
    for i != 0 {
        if true {
            err := db.Select(&item, `SELECT * FROM t_item LIMIT 10`)
            if err != nil {

            }
            err = db.Select(&categoria, `SELECT * FROM t_categoria LIMIT 10`)
            if err != nil {

            }
            err = db.QueryRow(`INSERT INTO t_categoria
                (
                    nome, 
                    ativo
                )
                VALUES ($1, $2)`, fmt.Sprintf("cateToTeste%v", i), true).Scan(&itemget)
            if err != nil {

            }

            err = db.Get(&itemget, `SELECT COALESCE(localidade_id, 0) 
                    FROM t_item 
                    WHERE id = $1`, 150)
            if err != nil {

            }

            log.Println("ok")
            i--
        }       
    }
    log.Println("Tudo ok!!")
```

Some time I get max connections and the application die.

Comment: Is that the only code that is using the db connection? If your app is only using `Get` then who knows what the problem is, but if your app is using other functionality of the `*sqlx.DB` type then that might be the problem, for example not closing `sql.Rows`, `sql.Stmt`, or `sql.Tx` values.

Comment: `sql.DB` is a pool of many connections which is managed internally. Are you possibly generating sufficient traffic that you are exhausting the pool? More info: https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/configuring-sqldb

Comment: @mkopriva I closing the connection only when the application stops (open and close connections all the time is not good for the application of course). But the problem is that the way I'm doing the thing, it should not open many connections, but some of them(like these using in the code block) still in use after the query and the application need open new ones to still working. I'm using tx, QueryRow, Get and Select, but not all application queries have this problem, just some pieces of code like that one.

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage the application just need open 2 connections per user to work. But if that ones still in use, It'll open another ones and arrive the limit (max connections) and the application die

Comment: @MarceloGonçalves `DB` is **not a connection**, it's a **pool of connections**. Every time you call a method like `QueryRow`, `Query`, `Get`, `Select` a connection is retrieved from the pool and when the method is done the connection is returned to the pool, most of the time this is done automatically, however in some cases you need to explicitly tell when you're done with the connection, if you do not then it will never be returned to the pool and after a while your pool will become empty and your app will crash.

Comment: ... for example if you use [`Query/QueryContext`](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.Query) or [`Queryx/QueryxContext`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB.Queryx) the returned [`*sql.Rows`](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Rows) object needs to be explicitly [`Closed`](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Rows.Close) after you're finished with it. If you don't close the rows object then your app will crash.

Comment: ... [`Stmt`](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Stmt) objects are the same they should be closed when not needed anymore. A [`Tx`](https://godoc.org/database/sql#Tx) must be either committed or rolled back, if not your app will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mkopriva !
I still don't know why the connections still in use, but to solve my problem I've use `Tx` and create a function to `defer` a `commit` or a `rollback` (commit and rollback both return a error, I was having problems to close the connections because that - in the `Tx` cases):

```
func commitORRollback(db *sqlx.Tx, ROLLBACK *bool) {
    if *ROLLBACK {
        if err := db.Rollback(); err != nil {
            ...
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```